# How to check if address is allowed to receive ERC721?

Tags: javascript, solidity

I have this list of address that I want to mint in Polygon Network:

```
["0x8d520d016246f31fe7a676648f1fd5e55ec5562d","0x5a52b317ed280c90d903d9605c2f41acbbc4b066","0x1bd7dabaae1b0d3f82cb47e182502b019f796b1c","0x35c81e79e1c49718db71b95179600e8c2472571d","0x4675e69560d9750a3682944a9dfa1b4fe3cda279","0x101a036ba89748a2c05431c7b088342758d38ab5","0x2bcc25c0cc7c8bb097b58b076b68574483af2985","0x55c052df9d0238a77dbf40931c26409c60955ff3","0x9024f7a9159e76b90029e0964f74d69d2b34c1a2","0x6441303870f67bbc3bb9665c6e951ed501d16233","0x2433ec4e8b0878ac4d7c7bf56e1fdf2b8977b06d","0x45d4bd22ca029d805cf971a2a53f884666e916df","0xbe6e3669464e7db1e1528212f0bff5039461cb82","0xd8dfba40a13df7f9270154bf13b293b732fea1f0","0x4772c5be232ba11daf20c1985c02338b0f8f871a","0xa691ea9bb77464c0a7def21a175a7d281dd44a0e","0x32619ea96a1260e7215bd71b711882769d5b3dc3","0xa28872727a46b0827527fb04540f52933db577ed","0x841ce48f9446c8e281d3f1444cb859b4a6d0738c","0xe7f80963f9ec6c449a120b68cae5571f87237e41","0xf7fbf80fa09975042ef620e8d6ef54af8bf2cc46","0xeb21e84c68d8e9fb4371e3b3686ecdf5e81de689","0x661d3005506aea3def4422606b1a31be9cef1d80","0xef9702ea316e52b4e771ef3ba81930320c4b88e6","0x4e3144dcd9b91a6acd7ea238afb74fb789fcd03a","0xf7b30915db932ec94e04a7f0208a63cc8eb87aa9","0x0c3d5fb65c2bdf9aaffc420303c523b55c3dca6c","0x16f33b3d0272f897d9bc55282fa151215215602c","0x4081c28448038d4eca175e89312c174fdf9c6a0d","0x22475406fa38e0747d88766dc38417ecc73e4adf","0xc22f5b5ccf5c718582460e6450391f738fdaf005","0xab25a1276b9fa7e2cb64b6e858cdc35d71213e48","0xc830cf22bbb93f5eaf380496054f74d497499cec","0x9619d3fa1f29c1de8fcfacedc07321637c1f0c3b","0x961c90b02232c2678eaf864627eaa20438d70ef2","0xfbb6aa0ba4a9ee610b9f0fea384e9d597c676a5f","0x4327342ccc2b7dd74751a5193ceb36ba5ce33567","0xcd5e2f67325d01bf4d9535a939428e2d8dab261d","0x81513aedaf902b0024168616de85361e5ff9cc28","0x166ed9f7a56053c7c4e77cb0c91a9e46bbc5e8b0","0x57043ee3d107de959e55e6932892874623fc961d","0x2831c1a4bbf6d7f5af915f0e09767a0463e12cfa","0x6a4d2b58a53b2dc960be1a888f279426a97b847f","0xd5f6f246507ffa6191c9d1851474dfe1782c5d25","0xc40bdf4aa875b6104381901e064f16bcb775789f","0xebb2db2d6c51a68bdee10470fe994fe3a4e53d23","0xd39a43b25f38e1ff7ec48420bff88743386688d6","0xfe03ea2901ffc6db88e7dc2410b0e98dff8f50ab","0x726dd921b64ebd09318e827d13f28047aa4a18d2","0xd46b4d81aa6764d00e61ee217a4f5cecd9aa189b"]
```

All the address are valid, due to:

```
/**
 * Checks if the given string is an address
 *
 * @method isAddress
 * @param {String} address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
var isAddress = function (address) {
  if (!/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i.test(address)) {
    // check if it has the basic requirements of an address
    return false;
  } else if (/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/.test(address) || /^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/.test(address)) {
    // If it's all small caps or all all caps, return true
    return true;
  } else {
    // Otherwise check each case
    return isChecksumAddress(address);
  }
};

/**
 * Checks if the given string is a checksummed address
 *
 * @method isChecksumAddress
 * @param {String} address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
var isChecksumAddress = function (address) {
  // Check each case
  address = address.replace('0x','');
  var addressHash = sha3.keccak256(address.toLowerCase());
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
    // the nth letter should be uppercase if the nth digit of casemap is 1
    if ((parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7 && address[i].toUpperCase() !== address[i]) || (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) <= 7 && address[i].toLowerCase() !== address[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

But I still get the following error:

```
PATCH /smart/airdrop/polygon Error: execution reverted: ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer
0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000324552433732313a207472616e7366657220746f206e6f6e20455243373231526563656976657220696d706c656d656e7465720000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address that you are using are valid, but in the version of the erc721 contract that you are using (I'm not sure is this behavior has changed in the version 4 of openzeppelin contracts) in order to receive an erc721 in a contract the contract should have implemented this https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Receiver , in order to prevent tokens being locked in contracts

Comment: The smart contract that I created does have this implemented, the problem is that the address that I want to mint the ERC721 probably isn't a user valid address. The question is how do I validate that before I try to mint.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this using web3js library:

```
            async isERC721Receiver(smartContractAddress){
                try{
                    const abi = [{"inputs": [{"internalType":"address","name": "operator","type": "address"},
                        {"internalType":"address","name": "from","type": "address"},
                        {"internalType":"uint256","name": "tokenId","type": "uint256"},
                        {"internalType":"bytes","name": "data","type": "bytes"}],
                    "name": "onERC721Received",
                    "outputs": [{"internalType":"bytes4","name": "","type": "bytes4"}],
                    "stateMutability":"pure","type": "function"}];
        
                    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, smartContractAddress);
                    
                    const r = await contract.methods.onERC721Received('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 0, []).call();
                    
                    return r === '0x150b7a02';
                }
                catch (_) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```